# Render component index in Magnolia template script

Tags: java, freemarker, magnolia

I am using Magnolia 5.6 Enterprise Pro CMS and I have an area of type list with one available component:

```
areas:
  steps:
    renderType: freemarker
    availableComponents:
      step:
        id: obi-module:components/step
```

So I can add N components of the same type to the *steps* area.

**Problem:** Now I want to display the component index in the *step* component's template script, but I don't know how to achieve this.

In the outer component's template script I can do the following:

```
[#assign stepList=cmsfn.children(content.steps) ]

...

<p>Number of steps: ${stepList?size!'#'}</p>

...

[#list stepList as component]
    [@cms.component content=component contextAttributes={'index':component?counter} /]
[/#list]
```

and in the template script of the *step* component I can use the *index* variable:

```
${(ctx.index)!'#'}
```

This shows the 1-based index number as desired but now in Magnolia I cannot edit the components any more since I don't get the typical green Magnolia editor bar for the *step* components.

When I put the template script like this:

```
[#assign stepList=cmsfn.children(content.steps) ]

...

<p>Number of steps: ${stepList?size!'#'}</p>

...

[@cms.area name="steps" /]
```

I can edit the components, but I don't know how to get the (list) index.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: I know nothing about the Magnolia specific part, but noted something unrelated. `${list?size!'#'}` will never print `#`. If you want to do that when `list` is missing, then you need `${(list?size)!'#'}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**My bad** - I was iterating over the step components from the (outer) steps component's script but I have to do it within an area script. So I changed my steps component definition to this:

```
areas:
  steps:
    renderType: freemarker
    templateScript: /my-module/components/steps-area.ftl
    availableComponents:
      step:
        id: my-module:components/step
```

And the area template script (steps-area.ftl) simply looks like this:

```
[#list components as component]
    [@cms.component content=component contextAttributes={'index':component?counter} /]
[/#list]
```

Answer (score 0):

it's a freemarker builtin called `_index` ... you could try this:

```
    [#list components as component ]
        Component Number: '${component_index + 1!}'
        [@cms.component content=component /]
    [/#list]
```

EDIT: if that doesn't work, try `component?index` instead of `component_index` ... just depends on the freemarker version shipped with magnolia for the version of magnolia you are using.

Comment: Hey Bradley, you render the index within the (outer) steps component's script, I pass it to the inner step component's script via the contextAttributes. But again, when I iterate over the components I don't have the green Magnolia editor bar around the inner step components to configure them. I only have these green bars when I use the @cms.area freemarker directive.